# How to fetch data from local JSON file on react native?

Tags: json, react-native, local-files

How can I store local files such as JSON and then fetch the data from controller?

Answer (score 196, accepted):

Since React Native 0.4.3 you can read your local JSON file like this:

```
const customData = require('./customData.json');
```

and then access customData like a normal JS object.

Comment: Is this syntax still supported ? because i can't use this syntax in my code.

Comment: Seems to work with React Native 0.26.2 for iOS. You might want to check with `react-native -v` and try reading the `package.json`.

Comment: customData only storing first 3500 character of file customData.json, Any other way to load large file @peter

Comment: @Akki Divide it into multiple smaller files?

Comment: It works perfectly - Q: Why can't I use import syntax instead?

Comment: As mentioned by @PaulMest, the better solution for now is: 
`import customData from './customData.json';`

Comment: Is the `require('file')` a call to the backend/server in React similar to `fetch('function_that_returns_json_in_nodejs')` in plain js?

Answer (score 151):

ES6/ES2015 version:

```
import customData from './customData.json';
```

Comment: could it have any name or does it have to be `customData `

Comment: @farmcommand2 It can be any name. `import myJsonFile from './foobar.json';`

Comment: I just tried with React Native 0.57, and looks like the .json extension is not necessary.

Comment: @ManuelZapata That is correct. If you exclude the suffix, the module resolver will try different extensions until it finds one that works. More info here: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together

Answer (score 29):

For ES6/ES2015 you can **import** directly like:

```
// example.json
{
    "name": "testing"
}


// ES6/ES2015
// app.js
import * as data from './example.json';
const word = data.name;
console.log(word); // output 'testing'
```

If you use typescript, you may declare json module like:

```
// tying.d.ts
declare module "*.json" {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}
```

Comment: You cannot say `import * as data from './example.json'` because that will try to assign all inner elements as data. Instead, you must use `import data from './example.json'`.

Answer (score 15):

Use this

```js
import data from './customData.json';
```

Answer (score 10):

The following ways to fetch local JSON file-

**ES6** version:

`import customData from './customData.json';`
or `import customData from './customData';`

If it's inside **`.js`** file instead of **`.json`** then import like -

```
import { customData } from './customData';
```

for more clarification/understanding refer example - [Live working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/read-from-local-json-fileso-qw4x9)

Answer (score 3):

maybe you could use [AsyncStorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html#content) **setItem** and **getItem**...and store the data as string, then use [the json parser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)   for convert it again to json...

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this Github issue:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/231

They are trying to `require` non-JSON files, in particular JSON. There is no method of doing this right now, so you either have to use AsyncStorage as @CocoOS mentioned, or you could write a small native module to do what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same requirement like above I have found the above mentioned ways helpful just to add more clarity and I have followed below ways to access `json` array from a `.js` file or `.json` file like below

**1st Method :**

**Step - 1:** Create a `js` file like below and add the custom data into that `json array` like below

**data.js**

```
export const DATA = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'The Hunger Games'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: 'Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: 'To Kill a Mockingbird'
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      title: 'Pride and Prejudice'
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      title: 'Twilight'
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      title: 'The Book Thief'
    },
    {
      id: 7,
      title: 'The Chronicles of Narnia'
    },
    {
      id: 8,
      title: 'Animal Farm'
    },
    {
      id: 9,
      title: 'Gone with the Wind'
    },
    {
      id: 10,
      title: 'The Shadow of the Wind'
    },
    {
      id: 11,
      title: 'The Fault in Our Stars'
    },
    {
      id: 12,
      title: "The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy"
    },
    {
      id: 13,
      title: 'The Giving Tree'
    },
    {
      id: 14,
      title: 'Wuthering Heights'
    },
    {
      id: 15,
      title: 'The Da Vinci Code'
    }
  ];
  
  export default DATA;
```

**Step - 2:** Now accessing and showing in a list from `App.js` file so first I have imported like below and showing in a list

```
import DATA from './data';
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import DATA from './data';
import { SafeAreaView,StyleSheet, View, Text}  from 'react-native';

const App = () => {

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}}>
    <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
        {DATA.map((item)=> 
        {return(
          <View style={{flex:1,borderBottomColor:'red',borderBottomWidth:2,marginHorizontal:12,justifyContent:'center'}} key={item.id}>
           <Text numberOfLines={1} style={{fontSize: 24, fontWeight: '400'}}>{item.title}</Text>
        </View>
        )})}
    </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
)
}
```

and then below screenshot is the result for both the methods followed.
Just to add both `App.js` and `data.js`, `items.json` are present in the same folder.

**2nd Method :**

**Step - 1:** Create a `json` file like below and add the custom data into that `json array` like below

**items.json**

```
[
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "The Hunger Games"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "title": "To Kill a Mockingbird"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "title": "Pride and Prejudice"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "title": "Twilight"
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "title": "The Book Thief"
    },
    {
      "id": 7,
      "title": "The Chronicles of Narnia"
    },
    {
      "id": 8,
      "title": "Animal Farm"
    },
    {
      "id": 9,
      "title": "Gone with the Wind"
    },
    {
      "id": 10,
      "title": "The Shadow of the Wind"
    },
    {
      "id": 11,
      "title": "The Fault in Our Stars"
    },
    {
      "id": 12,
      "title": "The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy"
    },
    {
      "id": 13,
      "title": "The Giving Tree"
    },
    {
      "id": 14,
      "title": "Wuthering Heights"
    },
    {
      "id": 15,
      "title": "The Da Vinci Code"
    }
  ]
```

**Step - 2:** Now accessing and showing in a list from `App.js` file so first I have imported like below and showing in a list

```
import DATA from './items.json';
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import DATA from './items.json';
import { SafeAreaView,StyleSheet, View, Text}  from 'react-native';

const App = () => {

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}}>
    <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
        {DATA.map((item)=> 
        {return(
          <View style={{flex:1,borderBottomColor:'red',borderBottomWidth:2,marginHorizontal:12,justifyContent:'center'}} key={item.id}>
           <Text numberOfLines={1} style={{fontSize: 24, fontWeight: '400'}}>{item.title}</Text>
        </View>
        )})}
    </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
)
}

export default App;
```

[image]