# loading json data from local file into React JS

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, xmlhttprequest, reactjs

I have a React component and I want to load in my JSON data from a file. The console log currently doesn't work, even though I'm creating the variable **data** as a global

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react/addons');

// load in JSON data from file
var data;

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.onload = reqListener;
oReq.open("get", "data.json", true);
oReq.send();

function reqListener(e) {
    data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
}
console.log(data);

var List = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {data: this.props.data};    
  },
  render: function() {
    var listItems = this.state.data.map(function(item) {
        var eachItem = item.works.work;        

        var photo = eachItem.map(function(url) {
            return (
                <td>{url.urls}</td> 
            )
        });
    });
    return <ul>{listItems}</ul>
  }
});

var redBubble = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      return (
        <div>
          <List data={data}/>          
        </div>
      );
    }
  });

module.exports = redBubble;
```

Ideally, I would prefer to do it something like this, but it's not working - it tries to add **".js"** onto the end of the filename.

```
var data = require('./data.json');
```

Any advice on the best way, preferably the "React" way, would be much appreciated!

Comment: The `console.log` works just fine, you're just calling it before `reqListener` is ever called.

Comment: Thanks for reply Jordan. In the code it's coming after reqListener, so I'm not sure if I understand. Could you elaborate please?

Comment: Your Ajax request takes time. JavaScript doesn't wait for the request to finish before moving on to the next instruction (because the request could take minutes or even hours to complete). We call this "asynchronous" (or sometimes "non-blocking") execution. Immediately after `send()` is called, `console.log` is called... and some time later the Ajax request finishes and `reqListener` is called. If you want something to happen only after the Ajax request is completed, you have to make that thing happen in `reqListener`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between synchronous and asynchronous programming (in node.js)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16336367/what-is-the-difference-between-synchronous-and-asynchronous-programming-in-node)

Comment: Thanks Jordan, that does make sense now. Thanks for taking the time to explain and the other link helped. I tried to move all my React code inside the reqListener, so it would work in the callback, but that seems like a bad idea. Is there a way to wait for the response before running the rest of the code? Thanks again.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are opening an [asynchronous connection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests#Asynchronous_request), yet you have written your code as if it was synchronous. The `reqListener` callback function will not execute synchronously with your code (that is, before `React.createClass`), but only after your entire snippet has run, and the response has been received from your remote location.

Unless you are on a zero-latency quantum-entanglement connection, this is *well* after all your statements have run. For example, to log the received data, you would:

```
function reqListener(e) {
    data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    console.log(data);
}
```

I'm not seeing the use of `data` in the React component, so I can only suggest this theoretically: why not **update** your component in the callback?

Comment: Thanks very much for your help John. I've been looking into how to update the component on the callback but not having much luck. Is it to do with the state? I'm still a newbie to React! 

I've updated the code to show how the component is working - are you able to tell me how to pass the data in on callback? Thanks again!

Comment: @Desmond Yes, state can work, as a component will be rerendered when its state changes.

Comment: `zero-latency quantum-entanglement connection`  maybe it's time to invent those, just so that people don't have to learn about async anymore...

Answer (score 198):

I was trying to do the same thing and this is what worked for me (ES6/ES2015):

```
import myData from './data.json';
```

I got the solution from this answer on a react-native thread asking the same thing:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/37781882/176002

Comment: If you're using this method with webpack, you need json-loader for the imported json files.

Comment: Thank you! I've been looking for a simple way to access json data in JSX, and this is exactly it!

Comment: Note that this will compile your JSON into the bundle, making hot-swapping JSON files impossible. That's probably fine for a lot of use cases, but it wasn't for mine.

Comment: this answer should be marked as the most accurate answer, but with `json-loader` package example

Comment: Worked for me. I’m using rollup. Previously had `var data = import(‘./data.json’)` which imported a Promise. Changing this to `import data from ‘./data.json’` gave direct access to the imported object.

Answer (score 29):

The simplest and most effective way to make a file available to your component is this:

```
var data = require('json!./data.json');
```

Note the `json!` before the path

Comment: This will not work unless you add a library for that. As this is not supported by default in React. example library :- https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-loader

Comment: `json-loader` is included with newer Webpack versions, I believe, but you may still need to add something to your Webpack config to use that exact syntax. Do some research into it.

Comment: @agm1984 things have changed since 2015, it would be nice if you provide a complete answer instead.

Comment: I believe the newest Webpack versions include json-loader so you do not need to install it or declare it in your config file. I would recommend trying to just `import FILE_AS_VARIABLE from './file/location.json'`

Comment: See answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43735486/load-static-json-file-in-webpack

Comment: Also see the answer in this question by `rockfakie`

Comment: with React v16.11.0 and a default project init, was able to simply add `var data = require('./data.json');`

Answer (score 15):

1. Install `json-loader`:

```sh
npm i json-loader --save
```

2. Create `data` folder in `src`:

```sh
mkdir data
```

3. Put your file(s) there.
4. Load your file:

```js
var data = require('json!../data/yourfile.json');
```

Comment: A had the "Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression" error when NOT using `json!`. Thanks.

Comment: is there anyway that I can use .json file from outside of the src folder? I am using create-react-app for my project

Answer (score 14):

If you have couple of json files:

```
import data from 'sample.json';
```

If you were to dynamically load one of the many json file, you might have to use a `fetch` instead:

```
fetch(`${fileName}.json`)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data))
```

Answer (score 5):

My JSON file name: terrifcalculatordata.json

```
[
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Vigo",
      "picture": "./static/images/vigo.png",
      "charges": "PKR 100 per excess km"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Mercedes",
      "picture": "./static/images/Marcedes.jpg",
      "charges": "PKR 200 per excess km"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Lexus",
        "picture": "./static/images/Lexus.jpg",
        "charges": "PKR 150 per excess km"
      }
]
```

First , import on top:

```
import calculatorData from "../static/data/terrifcalculatordata.json";
```

then after return:

```
  <div>
  {
    calculatorData.map((calculatedata, index) => {
        return (
            <div key={index}>
                <img
                    src={calculatedata.picture}
                    class="d-block"
                    height="170"
                />
                <p>
                    {calculatedata.charges}
                </p>
            </div>
```

Comment: Adding code is great but you need to explain your code with comments.

Comment: yes! but I explain in short way. Next time I will try to add code with explanation. thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could add your JSON file as an external using webpack config. Then you can load up that json in any of your react modules.

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30602665/6886570)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load the file, as part of your app functionality, then the best approach would be to include and reference to that file.

Another approach is to ask for the file, and load it during runtime. This can be done with the [FileAPI](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/). There is also another StackOverflow answer about using it:
[How to open a local disk file with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582671/how-to-open-a-local-disk-file-with-javascript)

I will include a slightly modified version for using it in React:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: null
    };
    this.handleFileSelect = this.handleFileSelect.bind(this);
  }

  displayData(content) {
    this.setState({data: content});
  }

  handleFileSelect(evt) {
    let files = evt.target.files;
    if (!files.length) {
      alert('No file select');
      return;
    }
    let file = files[0];
    let that = this;
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      that.displayData(e.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
  }

  render() {
    const data = this.state.data;
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="file" onChange={this.handleFileSelect}/>
        { data && <p> {data} </p> }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```