# Load and display json data in react component

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to load in data from a json file in a react component. I am trying this solution in my app.js.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33141549/1937021

```
var data = require('json!../json/acordes.json');
```

"Cannot resolve module JSON error" in the terminal.

I do this in the app.js file. My folder structure is as follows:

```
/src
  /js
    app.js
  /css
  /json
    acordes.json
```

The rest of my code looks like this:

https://gist.github.com/dabit3/651f2dae058ff99810eb771c2817d622

Comment: How are you building your bundle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I may be mistaken, but in order to be able to require json in such a way, you have to use `webpack` with [`json-loader`](https://github.com/webpack/json-loader).

Assuming, you use webpack. Install `json-loader`:

```
npm install --save json-loader
```

And add to webpack loaders:

```
//.. 
loaders: [
  {test: /\.json$/, loader: "json", include: "path/to/your/sources"}
]
```

Comment: I did this but now I get ´ERROR in ./~/json-loader!./src/json/acordes.json
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token m
    at Object.parse (native)
    at Object.module.exports (/Users/alexanderlloyd/Documents/tocacuatro/node_modules/json-loader/index.js:7:48)
 @ ./src/js/App.js 66:11-47´

Comment: Could you please provide your json file?