# Load static JSON file in Webpack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, webpack

I have somewhere in my code following construction:

```
var getMenu = function () {
    return window.fetch("portal/content/json/menu.json").then(function (data) {
        return data.json();
    });
};
```

I tried in my `webpack.config.js` this:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        ...
        {
            test: /\.json$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: [
                'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]&outputPath=portal/content/json'
            ]
        },
        ...
   ]
}
```

**Project structure**:

```
dist
  content
     json
        menu.json <- this is missing

src
  content
     json
       menu.json <- source file
```

**Question:**

How can webpack copy `src/content/json/menu.json` to `dist/content/json/menu.json` ?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You're using `fetch` to request a JSON file and that will only happen at runtime. Furthermore, webpack only processes anything that is imported. You expected it to handle an argument to a function, but if webpack did that, every argument to a function would be considered a module and that breaks any other use for that function.

If you want your loaders to kick in, you can import the file.

```
import './portal/content/json/menu.json';
```

You can also import the JSON and use it directly instead of fetching it a runtime. Webpack 2 uses [`json-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/json-loader) by default for all `.json` files. You should remove the `.json` rule and you would import the JSON as follows.

```
import menu from './portal/content/json/menu.json';
```

`menu` is the same JavaScript object that you would get from your `getMenu` function.

Comment: I use the latter option you gave but I get Cannot find module 'givenPath'.

Comment: What if you don't use fetch? Is it possible to do what's OP is asking?

Comment: [json-loader is not required anymore](https://webpack.js.org/migrate/3/#json-loader-is-not-required-anymore)

Answer (score 14):

if you'd like your json to be loaded in runtime/deferred you can use awesome webpack's [dynamic imports](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports) feature:

```
import(
    /* webpackChunkName: "json_menu" */
    './portal/content/json/menu.json'
);
```

it will return a Promise which resolves to the module object, with "default" field containing your data. So you might want something like this (with es6 it looks really nice):

```
import(
    /* webpackChunkName: "json_menu" */
    './portal/content/json/menu.json'
).then(({default: jsonMenu}) => {
    // do whatever you like with your "jsonMenu" variable
    console.log('my menu: ', jsonMenu);
});
```

Notice that dynamic imports require a babel plugin `syntax-dynamic-import`, install it with npm:

```
npm i babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import -D
```

Comment: This is a nice alternative to fetch, but still doesn't tell me how to get webpack to write the json file to the dist folder.

Comment: @Luminous it will be there automatically, whatever you imported anywhere is turned into chunks (see webpackChunkName: "json_menu") during the compilation. Final file name and path will be determined by the webpack config - if you're not satisfied with generated names - you can utilize the code splitting name callback to fine tune it