# JSON - Blender & ThreeJS - Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: json, reactjs, three.js, blender

I have exported a 3D model from Blender using the io_three addon.

Now I am trying to load this model into ThreeJS using code like this.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import * as THREE from 'three';
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load('./making_a_face10.json', handle_load);
```

I am consistently getting the same error message.

```
Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

I have tried using the THREE.ObjectLoader() and also this option https://github.com/tweedegolf/parsed-model, but it keeps saying error in position 0 of JSON.

As a side note, I can access the JSON like this:

```
var JSONdata = require('./making_a_face10.json');
```

That does expose data inside the JSON, but I want the ThreeJS loader to work.

Then I found this example https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_json_blender and when I went to view the source code it shows that the 'model' is being imported as a .js file??, i.e. they are loading it like this:

```
loader.load( 'models/animated/monster/monster.js', function ( geometry, materials )...
```

There is ample material to explain what I want to do but none of it points to loading the model as a .js file.

two more notes - the format of my JSON file looks extremely like this https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/models/animated/monster/monster.js and I am running a local server using `npm start`

If any whiz kid could help me out I would be extremely grateful.

**SOLVED**

In the React project folder. The .JSON file was in my `/src` folder. It should have been in my `/public` folder.

Comment: The error makes me think that you import isn't working correctly. Are you using webpack? You may need to add a json-loader to get it working.

Comment: Check out this example for loading a static JSON file in Webpack. You should try importing it as a variable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43735486/load-static-json-file-in-webpack

Comment: That error suggests that you're not getting the file you think you're getting - it's telling you that the initial character of the file is `<`. I usually see this error when I'm attempting to load something from an API and I'm getting a 404 or 500 error instead of the data I expect. I recognize that you're loading a local file, so it's probably not an HTML response, but... maybe this is a clue for you?

Comment: OMG, dude. I just did the exactly same thing hauhau. Webpack make us think that everything is bundled.

Answer (score -2):

As Kryten mentioned in the comments.. Your load is failing. The first character in your JSON file is not a '<'. That looks like an XML response failure header.

The THREE loader uses XMLHTTPRequest internally... you could try loading your JSON directly with XMLHTTPRequest and then log the output to see what the error is..