# Json file was not found by webpack

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, webpack, file-not-found

I am developing a small personal project,
i need to import json files with webpack but impossible

package.json contain:

```
    "webpack": "^4.17.1"
    "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
```

webpack.config.js contain

```
{ test: /\.json$/, use: 'json-loader' },
```

I dont know what vs code tell me this issue

```
import * as data from './loading.json';
- Cannot resolve module 'json' -
```

a question "Load static JSON file in Webpack" do not solve my problem and with json-loader or not this issue still present

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load static JSON file in Webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43735486/load-static-json-file-in-webpack) According to https://github.com/webpack-contrib/json-loader you don't have to use the `json-loader` when using webpack v2 and higher

Comment: My issue still present

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, you no longer need json-loader for `.json` since webpack 2.0.0.

However, if you are using json-loader because you don't want to bundle the json file, then I would recommend using one of the following solutions:

1. Use Copy Webpack Plugin to copy the json file into the build directory.
2. Use `type = 'javascript/auto'`

For example(note that this example uses **file-loader** instead of json-loader):

```
{
  type: 'javascript/auto',
  test: /\.json$/,
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'file-loader',
      include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')],
      options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]'
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Updated: Added `include`. Remember to place the json file in the src folder.

For more information, please check out this page:
[Webpack 4.0 file-loader json issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6586)

Comment: I tested this solution but it did not work, I also tested the solution to rename the .json in something else it does not work either the file can not be found

Comment: @terapha Then try adding `include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')]` to the config file. Remember to place the json file in the src folder