# How to include static files in a Node module and still make it available when used with webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I have two packages A and B. A is a general-purpose module, useful for e.g. both Node and browser. B is a project specific for the browser environment and it requires A, and uses Webpack.

A has `example.json`, which is read inside of the the files of A as

```
const {readFileSync} require('fs');
const {join: joinPath} require('path');
function getExample() {
    return readFileSync(joinPath(__dir, 'path/to/example.json'));
}
```

Inside package B, I would like to call `getExample()` but naturally the `fs` package is not available on the browser.

What kind of architecture should I rather use for this use case? Maybe (a) maybe I can `Webpack`ify project A. Or maybe I need some particular Webpack configuration for project B?

I'm fairly familiar with Node development but when it comes to the browser environment or Webpack, I'm totally lost!

Comment: Here's a question similar to yours. The accepted answer may help you:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43735486/load-static-json-file-in-webpack

Comment: Why not `require`ing the JSON instead of using `fs`?

Answer (score 0):

As implied by [mfarhadpur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6278431/mfarhadpur), you can just `require('./your/json/file)` in Node. That is, `require` can handle not only `.js` files but also `.json` files.

This removes altogether the need for using `fs` in my use case.