# How to import/Serve json file from another directory/local pc to generate datatable data in webpack?

Tags: javascript, json, webpack, import, fetch-api

[image: Sample json data in json file]**CODE** `const response = await fetch('/testdata/rows.json')`

**OR**

`const response = await fetch('rows.json')`

**ERROR thrown:**

`GET http://localhost:3000/testdata/rows.json 404 (Not Found)`

or other similar variations.

**How do I get the json file or txt file with json format data to be served or imported in the webpack so chartjs or google chart can use it to generate charts data???**

```
(async function() {
  

  //for express serving the file
  const response = await fetch('/testdata/rows.json')
  const data = await response.json();
     console.log(data);
     ...//////// code omitted for brevity
})();
```

In expressjs I can serve the file and use it with fetch(rows.json) but not able to achieve same functionality in webpack. How do I properly serve the file or import it to be used in project?

New to webpack implementation and usage, so please be descriptive.

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

when you have the local file, you don't need to fetch it.
you could create a folder in your app directory called for example "Data" and add the JSON file in this folder then you could simply require the file by the following code into the file that is needed

```
const testData = require('./Data/row.json');
```

or you could look at this answer it might help:
[Load static JSON file in Webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43735486/load-static-json-file-in-webpack/43742105#43742105)

Comment: throws error require is undefined even if I remove type module from html file when running in webpack. I figure I would have to use import for ES6. I have the file in a subfolder in directory but not able to find it when using webpack script to run the server.

Comment: you could look at this answer it may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43735486/load-static-json-file-in-webpack/43742105#43742105

Comment: hmm, thanks for that link. Unfortunately though, both of those answers didn't work for me. I did go down dynamic import rabbit hole mentioned in the second answer but I am stuck with error ` TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: http://localhost:3000/rows.json ` and I tried solutions for it as well. I am trying to import data from a json files with no default obejct just json data objects. I will try and link it in my question if I can, still new to this.