# How to fetch local json file into constructor in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have data.json file in my react app and I would like to use in my home.js file which have currently internally json values.

Is there any way to call data.json file into my this.state constructor.

```
class Home extends Component {
  constructor ()
{
  super();
  this.state={
    data:[
      {
        rank:1,
        name:'Name one',
        agency:'agency one',
      },
      {
        rank:2,
        name:'Name Two',
        agency:'agency two',
      },
      {
        rank:3,
        name:'Name Three',
        agency:'agency three',
      }
    ]
  }
}



render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {
          this.state.data.map((value) =>
          <div>
            <span>{value.rank}</span>
            <span>{value.name}</span>
            <span>{value.agency}</span>
          </div>
          )
        } 
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31758081/loading-json-data-from-local-file-into-react-js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import it as a default value then assign it in your state.

```
import data from "./data.json";

class Home extends Component {
  constructor ()
{
  super();
  this.state={
    data,
  }
}



render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {
          this.state.data.map((value) =>
          <div>
            <span>{value.rank}</span>
            <span>{value.name}</span>
            <span>{value.agency}</span>
          </div>
          )
        } 
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: Might have to use the spread operator here, like `this.state = { data: [ ... data ] }`

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider your JSON file `temp.json` stored in the same directory.
Assigning to `data` state on `constructor` like

```
 this.state = {
      package: require("./temp.json")
 };
```

Use like usual state. `this.state.data[0].rank` or map.

Example https://codesandbox.io/s/92qpzoz4rw

Comment: Thanks Revansiddh, for reply.
As I am absolute beginner in react so somehow not able to manage require method. It seems working once I use package.json as per codesandbox but one I use package: require("./json/data.json") file from my json folder somehow error seems.

But for now as per current scenario tweak suggested by devserkan works for me, I will surely 100% try this require method as well.

just one query, are you available if I have any doubt related your suggested method.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
1.  $ npm install load-json-file;
2. you can view also  load-json-file implementation detail here: https://github.com/sindresorhus/load-json-file

```
import loadJsonFile from 'load-json-file'
class Home extends Component {
  constructor ()
{
  super();
  this.state={data:''}

componentDidMount(){
loadJsonFile('data.json').then(json => {
    console.log(json);
    this.setState={data: json}
});

}


render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {
          this.state.data.map((value) =>
          <div>
            <span>{value.rank}</span>
            <span>{value.name}</span>
            <span>{value.agency}</span>
          </div>
          )
        } 
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```