# Loading JSON using TypeScript and ReactJS gives 'file not found'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

While loading a local JSON file in my ReactJS project written in typescript, I am getting an error like `file not found in path provided`.

The code I am currently using:

```
var data = require('./Localisation string.json')
Console.log(data);
```

The `console.log` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31758081/loading-json-data-from-local-file-into-react-js),

You should try below code:

```
var data = require('json!./data.json');
```

Comment: Still i am getting same error.. do i need to change anything in config file?