# react-native AutoComplete text input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

For example, I have a list of towns. I need to create something like 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpuMb.png)

How to create it (for Android and IOS)? And where I should to store it?

Comment: We need more information to help. Have you got the data stored locally ? Are you getting the data with a request ? Maybe post some code so we can see where your problem lies.

Comment: My data stored in json file.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

OK, so based on the little information you've given us, I tried to make a quick example (no design at all) that you can find [here](https://rnplay.org/apps/M4tiAQ)

I'll let you do the styling.

Reading your data from the JSON file : check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29452822/how-to-fetch-data-from-local-json-file-on-react-native)

The code is the following :

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  Component,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  ListView,
  View,
} = React;

var adresses = [
  {
    street: "1 Martin Place",
      city: "Sydney",
    country: "Australia"
    },{
    street: "1 Martin Street",
      city: "Sydney",
    country: "Australia"
  }
];

var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});

class SampleApp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      searchedAdresses: []
    };
  };

  searchedAdresses = (searchedText) => {
    var searchedAdresses = adresses.filter(function(adress) {
      return adress.street.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchedText.toLowerCase()) > -1;
    });
    this.setState({searchedAdresses: searchedAdresses});
  };

    renderAdress = (adress) => {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{adress.street}, {adress.city}, {adress.country}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput 
            style={styles.textinput}
            onChangeText={this.searchedAdresses}
            placeholder="Type your adress here" />
        <ListView
                    dataSource={ds.cloneWithRows(this.state.searchedAdresses)}
          renderRow={this.renderAdress} />
      </View>
    );
  };
}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
  },
  textinput: {
    marginTop: 30,
    backgroundColor: '#DDDDDD',
    height: 40,
    width: 200
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SampleApp', () => SampleApp);
```

Comment: thanks for this solution!

Comment: It's no longer available...

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: @Gp2mv3 I put the code in a snack: https://snack.expo.io/@niklasro/readjson

Comment: ListView deprecated. Any other options available in order to achieve this