# Syntax error: Unexpected token m in JSON at position 0 in React App

Tags: json, reactjs

I am new to ReactJS,now working on small project. I am trying to load data from a JSON file,but I'm getting this **"Syntax error: Unexpected token m in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse ()"**. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code :

```
import React from 'react';
import dataa from './src/dataa.json';
class App extends React.Component {
constructor() {
  super();

  this.state = {
     data:require('json!./dataa.json')

   }
 }

render() {
  return (
     <div>
        <Header/>
        <table>
           <tbody>
              {this.state.data.map((person, i) => <TableRow key={i} data={person} />)}
           </tbody>
        </table>
     </div>

      );
    }
   }


 class TableRow extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
       <tr>
        <td>{this.props.data.id}</td>
        <td>{this.props.data.name}</td>
        <td>{this.props.data.age}</td>
        </tr>
        );
      }
   }

    export default App;
```

and JSON data:

```
[{"id":"1","name":"Smith","age":"20"},
{"id":"2","name":"Jackson","age":"94"},
{"id":"3","name":"Doe","age":"80"},
{"id":"4","name":"Johnson","age":"37"}]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fetch data from local JSON file on react native?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29452822/how-to-fetch-data-from-local-json-file-on-react-native)