# in react, axios returns 404 error systematically

Tags: reactjs, axios, create-react-app

Context: I want to load an html file into a react application and display part of it in a help window. The html file can be updated anytime from some content generator, so translating it into jsx is not an option.

Right now I'm trying to load any file (json included) using axios and getting 404 response. I put the call in componentWillMount, componentDidMount, whatever. I've peppered the project with toto.html and toto.json files. I created the app using create-react-app

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class  Toto extends Component {
componentWillMount  ()  {
    console.log("inside componentWillMount")
    axios 
        .get('./toto.json') 
        .then(response => 
            { console.log("json response=",response);  })
        .catch( error => {
            console.log("json error=",error);} );
    axios
        .get('./toto.html')
        .then(response => 
            { console.log("html response=",response);  })
        .catch( error => 
            { console.log("html error=",error);} );
    console.log("inside componentWillMount 2")
};
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Toto TIti Tata</h2>
            <object type="text/html" data="./toto.html" ></object>
        </div>
    )
}};
export default Toto;
```

Response:

```
inside componentDidMount Toto.js:11
inside componentDidMount 2 Toto.js:30
html error= Error: "Request failed with status code 404"
createErrorhttp://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1555:15settlehttp://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1721:12handleLoadhttp://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1081:7 Toto.js:27
json error = Error: "Request failed with status code 404"
```

Comment: why `./toto.json`? it should be `/toto.json`

Comment: sorry, putting `/toto.json` instead of `./toto.json` changes nothing. I put `./toto.json` originally because the file was in the same folder as the component.

Comment: So you have static todo.json file? Then u can't read it like you are doing using `axios`. You need to setup a small express server, and then using the exposed api, u can read it using axios.

Comment: what do you mean by static?

Comment: I put the file on a server and now I get _Error: "Network Error"_ . Little by little...

Comment: but I can say now that you are on right path.. Seems like not all servers are running.. check that. or if urls are correct or not.

Comment: I found a first-level answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29452822/how-to-fetch-data-from-local-json-file-on-react-native 


Using require, you can import a json file and use it as a variable.
var customData = require('./toto.json');
console.log("customData=", customData)

When I try with an html file it says Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.