# How to read .json file in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am using React Native version 0.59.4.
I created a file data.json

But when I import this file like this

```
import myData from '../staticData/data.json';
```

I get this error `Bundle failed: Could not resolve module ...` and I made sure the path is correct

I also tried removing the extension but no change

I tried almost every solution here.

Is there anything more that I can try?

**EDIT**
I tried changing the extension from `.json` to `.js` and in that file I added export default { // json } and it worked like a charm.

Comment: You can try using
const myData = require('../staticData/data.json');

Answer (score 2):

Well, you are doing it right, I think you are messing with the path.
Are you sure that`s the right path, and how organized are your folders ????
another way to do that is to use the old JS way

```
const customData = require('./customData.json');
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems react native doesn't support .json extension

Comment: Look I'm pretty sure that supports it, but I'm not aware of the system that you are using your npm version and so on. I think you can look at here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29452822/how-to-fetch-data-from-local-json-file-on-react-native, and have some insights.

Comment: Thank you I will take a look